# 6 points in a rectangle puzzle

Tags: graph-theory

Six points are in a rectangle with dimensions $3$ by $4$. Prove that the distance between at least two of the six points is smaller than the square root of $5$. Note that points can be on the edges and corners.

General observations:

The diagonal of the rectangle has length $5$.

$\sqrt{5}$ is about $2.2$.

Putting a point on each corner, and one in the center of the rectangle will work.

The last point can not be put anywhere else.

I can see how to do it. I am not really sure how to write genuine proof on the problem though.